# How to make my name field unique

Tags: c#, api

How to make my `Name` Field in my api model unique?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `unique` respect to what?

Comment: i will make the name field unique. like username.

Comment: That would normally be something configured in some form of mapping to e.g. a database. As such, the details would usually depend on what sort of data layer technology you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can check from the ViewModel / Client-side without checking existing values in the database.

What I do is when I go to save the entity/object I do a database lookup and it will either pass or fail validation.

Heres an example using Entity Framework / Linq

```
using(var db = new DbContext())
{
     return db.User.Any(x => x.Name.Equals(modelName, StringComparison.IgnoreOrdinalCase)) 
                             ? false : true;
}
```

You didn't say what platform you were using so it's difficult to give you more specific advice.

EDIT:

If it's MVC Razor, it's easy.  You can inject error messages by adding them to the modelstate using the correct model property name

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(AddUserModel model)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // input parameters passed - now check for uniqueness in db
          using(var db = new DbContext())
          {
               if(!db.User.Any(x => x.Name.Equals(model.Name, StringComparison.IgnoreOrdinalCase)))
               {
                     // Add to database
                     return;
               }
               else
               {
                    // hard code string or get model property name via reflection etc
                    // Or if you want a general error you can use string.Empty as the key name and display via the validation summary
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name must be unique");

                    // Fall through and return error 
               } 
          }               
     }
     return View(model);
}
```

// View

```
// if you've used the helper this will all you need to show
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
// Or..
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Comment: how about in web api? like remote validation?